# Слайдер под jquery > 1.8

Tags: jquery, slider, изображения, html, css

Есть возможность адаптировать этот плагин под jquery старше 1.9 , дело в том, что он с 1.8 > не работает, а слайдер хорош www.tympanus.net/codrops/2011/04/28/rotating-image-slider/

Answer (score 3):

Любой плагин можно со старых версий перевести на новую. Подключите  [jQuery Migrate](http://jquery.com/download/) и вычисляйте устаревшие методы, заменяя их на новын аналоги. Вот к примеру [$.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/), который используется в том плагине - с версии 1.9 удален. Естественно, что он вызывает ошибку.

Comment: это первое что я сделал, потом выяснилось, что jquery.transform-0.9.3.min_.js работает неверно, вернее где-то в .each передается underfined и вылазят ошибки, уже 4 часа дебажу - получается что изображения не обрезаются и не прокучиваются

Comment: @dlis, а что вы предлагаете? Что бы кто-то за вас всю эту работу проделал? Тогда это на фриланс. Может кто и тут возьмется, но уж точно не я, по той простой причине, что мне этот плагин не нравится, а время тратить в пустую - желания нет.

Comment: можете предложить что-нибудь из слайдеров, где несколько изображений одновременно показывается, дело в том что большинство слайдеров заточены под широкоформатные изображения (ширина больше высоты), а предметная область предполагает "вертикальные изображения"

Comment: Предложить что-либо сложно, т.к. подавляющее большинство плагинов, так или иначе, надо адаптировать под себя. К примеру, [такой плагин][1]. Невзрачный на вид, но который можно превратить в "конфетку", поколдовав в CSS. Будете этим заниматься? Думаю, что нет. А найти то, что вам идельно подойдет без всяких корретировок - практически не возможно. По этой причине, я уже давно предпочитаю писать такие вещи самому, что гораздо приятней, чем копаться в чужом коде.

   [1]:http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#demo